# how to read a file from hex editor and find equivalent ASCII values in c++

Tags: c++

i have a file in hex looking like below

9C CB CB 8D 13 75 D2 11 91 58 00 C0 4F 79 56 A4
60 00 00 00 92 02 00 00 40 1F 00 00 80 14 00 00
A4 08 00 00 90 02 00 00 A0 09 01 00 40 AE 00 00
E4 27 00 00 90 02 00 00 A0 09 01 00 FC 7A 00 00
84 31 01 00 CF 01 00 00 A0 09 01 00 14 A7 00 00
24 3B 02 00 75 02 00 00 A0 09 01 00 50 8D 00 00
C4 44 03 00 14 02 00 00 A0 09 01 00 20 35 00 00
64 4E 04 00 C8 00 00 00 90 02 00 00 E8 03 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 CA 01 00 00 A4 00 00 00

first sixteen bytes (9C CB CB 8D 13 75 D2 11 91 58 00 C0 4F 79 56 A4) are showing header of my file.

Comment: Can you post some code and explain what have you tried since now?

Comment: its a windows address book file. i have crack its format by research on wab file. Now i am trying to write its c++ code to read the data from file.Can you tell me how to read all the contents of this file by a c++ program.

Comment: You don't want to 'read a file from a hex editor' at all. You just want to read the *file,* surely? That does everything you state automatically. Or do you really need to read a hex-editor output for some reason? Clarify.

Comment: yes i just want to read file. could you please help me ?

Comment: It is a windows address book file in microsoft outlook express.I wants to read and process all meaningful bytes in little indian. for example i read the hex byte 0x08A4 and store it in a location and now i wants to seek from starting to offset 0x08A4. And now from offset 0x08A4 i wants to read 4 bytes like 0x02B1D2. Now go to offset 0x02B1D2 and seek 24 bytes from current offset.Now i wants to read four bytes like 0x0FFF0102. And store these bytes in a memory buffer and retrieve some information from these byes. Could you please help me how can i process whole file like this

Answer (score 1):

This will convert the hexadecimal input to characters, and print them out (though the numbers 80 and greater won't actually be ASCII, since they're outside the range defined by ASCII):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

int main() { 
     std::transform(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin), 
                    std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
                    std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout),
                    [](std::string const &in) {
                        return (char) strtol(in.c_str(), NULL, 16); 
                    });
}
```

I'm not sure how much good that'll do for you, but it seems to be what you're asking, and without more information on what you really want, it's about as good as I think anybody can probably do.

Comment: i wants to read and process all meaningful bytes.

Comment: @azam42: Hard to do much about that, absent any description of which bytes are meaningful.

Comment: It is a windows address book file in microsoft outlook express.I wants to read and process all meaningful bytes in little indian. for example i read the hex byte 0x08A4 and store it in a location and now i wants to seek from starting to offset 0x08A4. And now from offset 0x08A4 i wants to read 4 bytes like 0x02B1D2. Now go to offset 0x02B1D2 and seek 24 bytes from current offset.Now i wants to read four bytes like 0x0FFF0102. And store these bytes in a memory buffer and retrieve some information from these byes. Could you please help me how can i process whole file like this.